# Por qué no puedo pasar las variables de un foreach a otro campo en php

Tags: php, foreach

Lo que quiero hacer es recoger unos `post` de otro programa a este de manera que pueda recoger los valores de esos `post` y poder grabarlos en una tabla.
El problema es que en la tabla `respuestasexa` me graba el último registro del `foreach` en todos los registros de la tabla, y sin embargo  cuando los saco por la pantalla salen bien.
Aquí os dejo lo que hago, gracias
Un saludo

```
foreach ( $_GET["respuesta"] as $selrespuesta) { 
$respuesta=$selrespuesta;   
$sql = "UPDATE respuestasexa SET respuestar = '$respuesta'";
mysqli_query($link, $sql);
echo "<p>respuestas: <b>".$respuesta."</b>";
}
```

Comment: En tu consulta no estás indicando ningún criterio de actualización: `UPDATE respuestasexa SET respuestar = '$respuesta'` eso hará que todas las filas de la tabla queden actualizadas al útimo valor que haya en la variable `$respuesta`. ¿Cuál es el criterio que deberías poner en el `WHERE laColumna=elCriterio`?

Answer (score 0):

Hola tu error esta aqui:

```
foreach ( $_GET["respuesta"] as $selrespuesta) { 
    $respuesta=$selrespuesta;   
    $sql = "UPDATE respuestasexa SET respuestar = '$respuesta'"; // esto Actualiza todos los registros
    mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    echo "<p>respuestas: <b>".$respuesta."</b>";
}
```

debería ser así:

```
foreach ( $_GET["respuesta"] as $selrespuesta) { 
    $respuesta=$selrespuesta;
    $quien = $_GET["quien"];
    $sql = "UPDATE respuestasexa SET respuestar = '$respuesta' WHERE Quien='$quien';";               
    mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    echo "<p>respuestas: <b>".$respuesta."</b>";
}
```

en pocas palabras en por cara iterarda al array debes indicar que quieres actualizar con la clausula `Where` y de algún lado debes sacar a quien vas a actualizar.

Comment: Gracias Francisco, problema solucionado :-)

Comment: @Jorge que bueno marca tu pregunta con la solución.